# Legendary forgotten Kingdom of Lechia

Tags: myth-identification, mythohistory, european-folklore

In the past I heard couple of legends about some mythic land in the north of Europe called [Lechia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lechia). But after reading couple of articles about legendary Kingdom of Lechia I decided to find more information about this Kingdom. Below I listed some of them and I wonder, is it something real or should we think about it as a legend/mythology?

**ANCIENT CITIES:**

- Kodan (nowadays polish city Gdańsk) – 1750 BC -> confirmed by [Pomponius Mela’s
  Map](https://digitalmapsoftheancientworld.com/ancient-maps/pomponius-melas-map/)
- Gniezno – (nowadays polish city Gniezno) - 1700 BC
- Carodom (nowadays polish city Cracow/Kraków) – 1550 BC
- Szczyt (nowadays polish city Szczecin) – 1450 BC
- Vineta - legendary town in the north - more [info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vineta)

**MEGALITHIC TOMBS:**

- Słonowice - ["Polish Valley of the Kings"](https://www.realmofhistory.com/2016/03/05/massive-megalithic-tombs-found-in-poland/) - 4000 BC (older that Valley of the Kings in Egypt) and one more [link](https://www.ancient-origins.net/news-history-archaeology/polish-pyramids-ruins-megalithic-tombs-time-stonehenge-discovered-poland-020755)

**GENETIC CLUE:**

- Haplogroup R1a (Y-DNA) - more info [here](https://www.eupedia.com/europe/Haplogroup_R1a_Y-DNA.shtml)

**ROMAN CONNECTION:**

- inscription - some info [here](https://www.jassa.org/?p=10666)

**TERITORY:**

- Sarmatia - info [here](https://www.bible-history.com/maps/romanempire/Sarmatia.html)
- Mare Sarmaticum (today Baltic see)
- and concept [Sarmatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarmatism) - well known in Poland

**CERAMIC:**

- Bronocice pot - 3400 BC - probably older wheel concept that Sumerian - more info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronocice_pot)

So my question is about existence of this kind of civilisation in the ancient time. Is it real or myth?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lech,_Czech,_and_Rus https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wielkopolska_Chronicle

Answer (score 3):

Lechia is the mythological name for Poland, stemming from the word Lech (which is also a common first name).

[image]

According to legend, the name derives from the first ruler of Poland, Lech. It is also the derivation for the term Lechitic languages.